# cakephp default controller/action routing with pagination breaks with named parameters

Tags: cakephp, routes, pagination, named-parameters

I have default routing rule set:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'index'));
```

when i go to

```
http://url.com/photos/index/page:1/limit:10/direction:desc/
```

everything works fine but it breaks when i go to

```
http://url.com/page:1/limit:10/direction:desc/
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to tell your route to parse after the `/`:

`Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'index'));`

Then, connect the named parameters:

`Router::connectNamed(false, array('defaults' => true));`

You can also set them within your route, if you prefer. More information on connecting named parameters here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#controlling-named-parameters